# convert dom4j docment to W3c document

Tags: java, xml, w3c, dom4j

I need to convert XML built with dom4j to a w3c document and don't have any idea about how do it.

Comment: Please provide more details as to what you want to do, it is really unclear to me, at least.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to go from:

```
org.dom4j.Document
```

To:

```
org.w3c.dom.Document
```

From the [dom4j quick start guide](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/guide.html):

```
Document document = ...;
String text = document.asXML();
```

From a [JavaRanch example](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/StringToDocument) on String to Document:

```
public static Document stringToDom(String xmlSource) 
        throws SAXException, ParserConfigurationException, IOException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    return builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlSource)));
}
```

Combine the 2 and you should have what you need.

Answer (score 9):

Check out DOMWriter. This works for me:

```
import org.dom4j.DocumentHelper;    
import org.dom4j.io.DOMWriter;

org.dom4j.Document dom4jDoc = DocumentHelper.createDocument();    
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc = new DOMWriter().write(dom4jDoc)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have large documents, you may want to avoid serializing your Document to text for performance reasons. In that case, it's best to use SAX events directly to do the transformation:

```
private static final TransformerFactory transformerFactory =
                                           TransformerFactory.newInstance();

public static org.w3c.dom.Document toW3c(org.dom4j.Document dom4jdoc)
         throws TransformerException {

    SAXSource source = new DocumentSource(dom4jdoc);
    DOMResult result = new DOMResult(); 

    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(); 

    transformer.transform(source, result);
    return (org.w3c.dom.Document) result.getNode();
}
```